# Upgrading to Angular15 throws error in IE 11

Tags: angular, typeerror, tsconfig, angular15

I have upgraded project to angular version 15. It was running in both chrome and IE 11. Now after upgrading angular to 15.1.1, with the below tsconfig.json settings, the app is not running in chrome and IE 11 with TypeError(TypeError: Class constructor ErrorHandler cannot be invoked without 'new').

`"compilerOptions": { "target": "es5"}`

I have gone through few questions in stackflow for the same error and learnt that in tsconfig.json target has to be modified to "es6" to resolve this error. so I changed as below.

`"compilerOptions": { "target": "es6"}`

After this it is working in chrome as expected.
But the app is not coming up in IE.
expected ) aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js (1,18) this is the error I'm seeing.

How do I fix this issue so that it runs in both IE and Chrome?

Im expecting application to run in both chrome and IE.
with target set to es6, it works in chrome bot not in IE.
with target set to es5, does not work in both chrome and IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular in not compatible with Internet Explorer since v13.